# Formalism or Empiric law related to first charge of battery (for Lithium)

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity

How could we explain that the first charge of battery is  tremendous for the following use of the phone. I mean , which model  (if it exists ) prooves us that first charge need to be complete ?

Intuively , I see that as an intial form of later charges so necesserely tremendous.

But formerly, we can't use just redox or thermo-cinetic to justify this. Because these last don't include notion of ageing.

I think a more complex model will be needed including material-surfaces properties. (here Lithium for most).

Thanks for sharing your knowledge on the existence of such a theory. (Don't need experiments , but may be empiric law as Keupert law)

Comment: So, you're asking why some batteries have to go through full charge/discharge cycles, otherwise they can lose their capacity?

Comment: Yeah. Absolutly